# Given several frames of a face that are not necessarily all frontal, how do you build a face recognition model?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have several videos that are labeled and have a bounding box around the face.  From the videos, I can subtract the background to get only the face.  However, all of the frames are not necessarily frontal.

How do you build a face recognition model based on this?  Is PCA appropriate in this case?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, because I don't know.  I believe this is an open research question, though; don't expect hard and fast answers.  (Though I'd love to be proven wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

That's a very difficult research problem. You might just want to see how far you can get with what facebook uses: http://face.com/